# Transit at Abu Dhabi International Airport without a UAE visa

Tags: uae, abu-dhabi, self-transfer, uzbek-citizens

After researching for couple of hours and also skimming through similar questions on this website, the question is: can a person transfer at Abu Dhabi International Airport without a visa, given that:
a. Nationality - Uzbekistan
b. Two separate tickets, one airline, i.e. Budapest-Abu Dhabi, UAE (Wizzair) + Abu Dhabi-Tashkent, Uzbekistan (Wizzair)
c. Time between flights 8 hours 35 minutes, will stay at Pearl Lounge (airside, Terminal A)
d. Only hand luggage, arrival and departure to/from terminal A
e. Limited time to apply for an online transit-visa (less than 36 hours remaining).
f. Emirates websites says this (https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=uz&destination=uz&transit=ae):

*Admission and Transit Restrictions:

Passengers must have a travel document with gender F or M to enter and transit.
Visa

Visa required.

TWOV (Transit Without Visa):

Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Additional Information:

Passengers transiting through Abu Dhabi (AUH) must have a confirmed airside hotel booking if their transit time is more than 24 hours*

Based on point f. above, Transit Without Visa option should be possible, however airline / airport personnel might think differently...

Any **similar** experience is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to get information on visa requirements directly from the country you are visiting, as other sources can become out of date. In this case, the relevant page on the country's website is https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/visit-visas/transit-visa

> Only the UAE based-airlines [Etihad and Emirates] you are travelling through can arrange your transit visa prior to your journey. If your trip is through a travel agency, the agency can also help you get the visa, but all visas are routed through the airline.

As you are not travelling with either UAE-based airline, you will not be eligible for the free transit visa.

[Wizz also have information on their website for passengers "Travelling to UAE"](https://wizzair.com/en-GB/information-and-services/travel-information/travel-documents)

> In compliance with the current regulations, authorities of the United Arab Emirates (UAE) request a valid visa as part of mandatory travel documents to enter the country for certain nationalities.

They link to a partner who can arrange tourist visas for Wizz customers.

Comment: Thank you for your message. Actually I read the link you provided and already applied for a transit visa via Etihad. Official website does not give a specific answer to this specific condition, unfortunately. I am considering all the options, in case visa is not issued before boarding the flight. The principal question boils down to whether TWOV (Transit Without Visa) can be applied in this instance, given the information above